# Why element() and remove() when we have peek() and poll() in java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

What is the use of having element() and remove() in Queue interface when we have peek() and poll()?

I checked the docs and found these methods are present in java 7 also.
The only difference mentioned is that element() and remove() throws an exception for empty queue.
We can manually throw an exception (in case we need that) if the queue is empty.

Was it truly necessary to keep both set of methods for this only difference? And if we start making different methods based on such differences I think java classes and interfaces will get filled with a LOT of methods. And is this a true object oriented style?

EDIT: Just to make my question clear, so I don't get the same "where you need exception use this, otherwise use that" answers.
What I can't understand is there are many such methods, where having an extra method with the same difference will be useful. So why its implemented only in some cases and not in others? Why the same principle was not applied overall? I can understand that maybe only the language creators can answer these why. **I want to know does this approach tally with OOPs principles?**

Comment: Java is quite conservative in this respect. See the range of methods or `Array` and similar classes in ruby, for example.

Comment: Of course they're present in Java 7. You can't just remove features from a product.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was it necessary? ...Possibly.  Maybe, maybe not.

In general, you should prefer `element()` or `remove()` if the queue should never be empty at this point in the program.  That's part of the general principle of failing fast: if something is wrong, throw an error as soon as possible so it can be debugged.  (If your program *doesn't* throw up as soon as a bug happens, then it gets significantly harder to trace that bug, because you only find out about it later on at a different place in the stack.)

That said, when you don't *know* if the queue is empty, and you want to find out, then exceptions have potentially unacceptable overhead, and returning null is probably preferable.

This was clearly a judgement call, and I can imagine that a different decision might have been made, but I think the call that was made is at least justifiable.  There are *good* reasons to prefer `element()` to `peek()` in some cases, and good reasons to prefer `peek()` to `element()` in other cases.

In terms of "why is this approach used in some cases and not others"...the answer varies, and it's *always* a highly subjective judgement call.  In many cases, the JDK frequently returns null on "failure" when null could never be a "positive" answer, and throws exceptions otherwise -- for example, `NavigableMap.firstKey()` can return null because null is the first key, so it throws a `NoSuchElementException` on an empty map, while `NavigableMap.firstEntry()` returns null on an empty map because there's no possibility of confusing `null` with a valid return.

Comment: thanks. I have edited the question so that what I am asking is more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is the difference.  If your Queue *should* have elements, use `element()` or `remove()`, so there's an exception if the Queue is empty.  If it is reasonable that the Queue can be empty, use poll() and peek() and deal with the `null` value.

As to whether this approach tallies with OOP principles - I don't think it's relevant.  OOP's three pillars (polymorphism, inheritance and encapsulation) don't cover the inclusion of methods of dubious necessity.  OOP isn't about solving efficiency & effectiveness issues.

Comment: The OP clearly knows the difference.  The OP's question is _why_ it was worth having methods with so little difference in the first place.

Comment: strikes me there's a significant difference between null and an exception

Comment: A significant difference...sure.  But I can also see the OP's point, that it might have been sufficient just to provide `peek` and `poll`, and not have exception-throwing methods at all, so why were those extra methods added?  That's a valid question, but it's not really answered by this answer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I disagree. This is the only possibly answer short of reading the designers' minds. Most of it is also contained in your answer.

Comment: I read the OP's question as "I can't imagine any reason for the designers to have done this; can people give reasons?"  "These are the differences between the methods" is not a reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is one semi-justified reason to include the exception-throwing methods: their existence allows a solution where a `null` is a legitimate item in the queue. Whenever you need such a scenario, without these methods you'd need to create a "null-sentinel" value that represents null; using the methods there is less boilerplate.